# Project management, job bags, accounting

Tags: process

I'm looking for a solution that would go from client/project creation through to timesheets and accounting.

Does anybody have any recommendations on a solution combination?

Problem is that at the accounting end, we need something that will output sage compatible data.

So, we need all the tools of say TeamLab or BaseCamp, pass client id, project number, invoice number, invoice etc.

Many thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you answered this question yourself: "So, we need all the tools of say TeamLab or BaseCamp, pass client id, project number, invoice number, invoice etc." Anyways, I'd go with basecamp.

Answer (score 1):

I really like and use Basecamp with Freshbooks for accounting. There is a Freshbooks / Sage connector out here, but I have no experience with it.